# nofollow in a form action

Tags: search-engines, nofollow

Imagine I have a page on my website that I don't want to be followed by robots. So I put a `rel='nofollow'` on every link to that page. 
Now imagine I have a form on another page which action is a link to that page. I heard that search engines try to post forms. If it is true, they will reach a page that I don't want to be indexed.

Am I falling into paranoia? Do search engines really try to post forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they will try to post the form. Anyway, the approach you're using could potentially have problems if someone else links to the page. If you don't want a page to be crawled by a responsible bot (like Google/Bing etc) then you should use the robots.txt file to disallow them from crawling it. If you don't have access to robots.txt you can do a similar thing with the robots meta tag. Adding the following to the head of the page you don't want indexed should work:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

Comment: This seems to be the perfect solution. thanks a lot !